# How to add blank line after every grep result using Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

How to add a blank line after every grep result?

For example, grep -o "xyz" may give something like -

```
file1:xyz
file2:xyz
file2:xyz2
file3:xyz
```

I want the output to be like this -

```
file1:xyz

file2:xyz
file2:xyz2

file3:xyz
```

I would like to do something like

```
grep "xyz" | perl (code to add a new line after every grep result)
```

Comment: Show some example input/output.

Comment: Fixed your example to make sure multi-line grep results are discussed

Comment: Why are you calling both grep and perl?

Comment: @tchrist, perhaps because I am ignorant of something?!

Comment: Well, perl is pretty good at pattern matching, better than grep is in   fact. But after your edit, I see what you are looking for now, and have updated by answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the direct answer to your question:

```
 grep 'xyz' | perl -pe 's/$/\n/'
```

But this is better:

```
 perl -ne 'print "$_\n" if /xyz/'
```

---

## EDIT

Ok, after your edit, you want (almost) this:

```
grep 'xyz' * | perl -pe 'print "\n" if /^([^:]+):/ && ! $seen{$1}++'
```

If you don’t like the blank line at the beginning, make it:

```
grep 'xyz' * | perl -pe 'print "\n" if /^([^:]+):/ && ! $seen{$1}++ && $. > 1'
```

---

**NOTE**: This won’t work right on filenames with colons in them. :)<sup>½</sup>

Comment: What's wrong with grep "xyz" | perl -pe 'print "\n"'  I don't understand what your if statement is doing.

Comment: @CodeBlue That version prints the newline before the line, not after. The `if` statement prints a newline before each new set of colon-tags.

Comment: @CodeBlue  The `do_something() if ! $seen{$whatever}++` idiom in Perl is extremely well-established.

Answer (score 1):

This prints a newline after every single line of grep output:

```
grep "xyz" | perl -pe 'print "\n"'
```

This prints a newline in between results from different files.  (Answering the question as I read it.)

```
grep 'xyx' * | perl -pe '/(.*?):/; if ($f ne $1) {print "\n"; $f=$1}'
```

Comment: Sorry.. that doesn't work according to the example, but instead prints a newline after every line grep returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use perl, you could do something like

```
grep "xyz" | perl -p -e 's/(.*)/\1\n/g'
```

If you want to use sed (where I seem to have gotten better results), you could do something like

```
grep "xyz" | sed 's/.*/\0\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a state machine to determine when to print a blank line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# state variable to determine when to print a blank line
my $prev_file = '';

# change DATA to the appropriate input file handle
while( my $line = <DATA> ){

  # did the state change?
  if( my ( $file ) = $line =~ m{ \A ([^:]*) \: .*? xyz }msx ){

    # blank lines between states
    print "\n" if $file ne $prev_file && length $prev_file;

    # set the new state
    $prev_file = $file;
  }

  # print every line
  print $line;
}

__DATA__
file1:xyz
file2:xyz
file2:xyz2
file3:xyz
```

Comment: That’s an um, *industrious* amount of effort. :)

Comment: Anything under 200 lines is a trivial program.